PHP_FPM extensions not loading in Apache
I'm building out a web server on Rocky Linux 9 with Apache and PHP 8.3. I need the pdo_dblib extension. From the command line via "php -m" and "php-fpm -m", I see that the pdo_dblib extension exists in both. However, when I dump phpinfo() in a browser, the pdo_dblib extension is not loaded.
Phpinfo shows that it's running PHP-FPM. I've noted the loaded configuration file at /etc/opt/remi/php83/php.ini, and the extensions directory at /etc/opt/remi/php83/php.d.
Here were my troubleshooting steps:

Checked the /etc/opt/remi/php83/php.d for the pdo_dblib extension. It wasn't there, so I added it.
Ran sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
Ran sudo systemctl restart httpd
Refreshed the web page with phpinfo(). Still not loaded.

Any ideas on why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Looks like you are confused with the various PHP stacks available

php-* (default versions)
php83-php-* (SCL, design for parallel installation)

Check the repository FAQ
For proper repository configuration and usage, following the Wizard instructions is recommended.
If you want a single version, I recommend to remove all php83 package and update the default version to 8.3.
dnf module switch-to php:remi-8.3/common
dnf install php-pdo_dblib

If you need multiple versions, and then using php83-* packages, you have to install the proper package (as explained by the wizard)
dnf install php83-php-pdo_dblib

And to check if it is there
php83 --modules


You're right. I figured this out last night. Somehow, when trying to install PHP 8.3 and the extensions I need on Rocky Linux 9, I managed to install both PHP/PHP-FPM and PHP83/PHP-FPM. This ended up created 2 PHP-FPM Unix sockets. I was making all of my changes to the PHP version, and Apache's config was set up to use the PHP83 version. I changed the Apache config to use the correct socket, removed PHP83, and now all is well.
